# Получение значений из другой функции

Tags: python

У меня есть функция

```
def opr(obj, s):
   obj = raw_input('Enter %s: ' % (s))
   ....обработка obj....
```

ей передаются аргументы из другой функции

```
def laptop(argv):
    val1 = val2 = val3 = val4 = None
    ......... # часть упущена
    if val1 is None:
        opr(val1, 'value1') #Здесь вал1 = None, почему не передается введенное значение ранее?
    if val2 is None:
        opr(val2, 'value2')
    if val1 and val2:
        search(str(val1), str(val2)) # Поэтому передается этой функции None
```

Как исправить сию ситуацию? 
search(obj1, obj2) - тоже функция

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def opr(s): 
  return raw_input('Enter %s: ' % (s))
```

в вызывающем коде:

```
val1 = opr('value1')
```

Comment: Дело в том, что obj мне нужен, я его обрабатываю в этой функции, сорри, не написал этого...

Comment: А чем тогда вообще идея вызова `opr(val1, 'value1')`? Насколько я понял это инициализация val1 в случае если он None. Если он Вам нужен, то инициализируйте другую переменную
`if not val1:
  val1_1 = opr("value1")`

Comment: После этой части - val1 = val2 = val3 = val4 = None 
идет проверка на количество введенных аргументов из командной строки...
А основная проверка obj происходит в вункции opr()

Comment: @Ardarik, и что мешает вернуть этот obj после обработки?

Comment: @Ardarik: зачем вообще передавать val1 в opr? Прочитайте введенные данные в obj и обработайте их там.

`def opr:
  obj = input()
  #...обработка...
  return obj`

Answer (score 1):

```
def opr(s):
    return raw_input('Enter %s: ' % (s))

def laptop(argv):
    val1 = val2 = val3 = val4 = None
    .........
    if val1 is None:
        val1 = opr('value1')
    .........
```

Comment: obj и s - ссылки на объекты в текущем контексте функции

    def opr(obj, s):
        obj = raw_input('Enter %s: ' % (s)) # заменяет значение ссылки obj в текущем контексте

Answer (score 0):

В начале `val1 = None` видимо далее его никто не переназначал...